# Imagecreatefromwebp(): WebP decode: fail to decode input data

Tags: php, image, jpeg, image-conversion, webp

I am trying to convert a webp file to JPEG using imagecreatefromwebp() but unfortunately, it throws me a warning: **Warning: imagecreatefromwebp(): WebP decode: fail to decode input data.**

Here's my code

```
$filename = dirname(__FILE__)."\\".$keyword."1.webp"; // $keyword = 'xyz';

$im = imagecreatefromwebp($filename);

// Convert it to a jpeg file with 100% quality
imagejpeg($im, './example.jpeg', 100);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

i am using this code, it works fine for me. Here `$data` contains the `base64encoded` data

```
$im = imagecreatefromwebp($data);
$imageResult = imagejpeg($im, $destinationPath . $fileName, 100);
imagedestroy($im);
```

The `imagecreatefromwebp()` function accepts either a valid `file` or `URL`. You can also pass the your binary data in that function. You can check the function definition and example here http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromwebp.php

Comment: RAUSHAN KUMAR you're right, this is the actual solution: `$data = file_get_contents ($filename); $image = @imagecreatefromwebp ('data://image/webp;base64,' . base64_encode ($data)); `  this works , whereas just supplying the filename directly fails. (also [thanks](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/imagecreatefromwebp/php-imagecreatefromwebp-function-examples.html) )

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the old question:

PHP:

Not fully supported WEBP for non-transparency, non-animated since version 5.4
  This means that WEBP image will becomes weird result for example: image is more green.

Fully supported for non-transparency, non-animated since version 5.6.

Fully supported for transparency, non-animated since version 7.0.

Not supported animated WEBP on all version (current version 8.3).

Can't find the reference but all are tested on Windows version of PHP+Apache NTS x86 & x64.